# Mongodb, get registers from last registered day

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection with many documents structured:

```
{
        "_id" : "skkbbp8TgnT3a2XgT",
        // ... other fields
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-12-08T21:03:37.141Z")
}
```

How can I find all the documents from the last registered day? And from the last five registered days?

Is it possible to do with only one statement?

Edit: Not duplicated. My question is to get all data from the last **registered** day, not how to query with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to pull the last registered date, chop off the time portion, and then compose a `$gte` query using just the date. Using `momentjs` makes it pretty simple. Assuming your collection name is called "Foo":

```
var lastDate = Foo.findOne({}, {
    sort: {
        createdAt: -1
    }
}).createdAt;

var startOf = moment(lastDate).startOf("day").toDate();

Foo.find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: startOf
    }
});
```

So you can do it in one line, but not recommended :)

```
Foo.find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: moment(Foo.findOne({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}).createdAt).startOf('day').toDate()
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! If I wanted for the last 5 registered days, maybe I need to use the skip in the lastDate statement.

Comment: That's a little more complicated. What if there were multiple days between days that people registered? You would have to somehow get the unique days from the database that people registered (ordered by most recent day)

Comment: Yes, perhaps using aggregate.